# Is this thermal paste or a thermal pad?

Tags: thermal-paste, thermal-pads

The thermal paste in my laptop's CPU's heat sink kind of looks like a thermal pad.  I'm little confused about what it is, and if I should clean it off...here is an image of the thermal paste or pad and the CPU:

[image: heat sink]

[image: cpu]

Comment: It's a thermal paste pad; unless it's dried out you really should not replace it

Comment: Thermal paste would barely cover the chip and would be much thinner. This is a thermal pad.

Comment: I cleaned out the center of the (thermal-pad ? thermal-paste-pad?) because I thought I could put my mx-2 in there...but I guess not...Which is it?  A thermal-pad or a thermal-paste-pad?

Comment: Now that you removed the heat sink, _it’s imperative to replace the paste/pad/mystery goo_. Otherwise, proper heat dispersal cannot be guaranteed. Only when you remove it immediately after applying new paste can you mount it again without replacing the paste.

Answer (score 1):

It is a thermal pad, now you need to remove it and clean all the cooper and the micro. Then you can use another thermal pad that fits or simply put a bit of thermal paste (like one grain of rice) on the microprocessor.

[image]